# Angular отправка запроса на сервер

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express

Добрый день, пишу на Angular js express js (node) на anular пишу

```
$scope.showAlert = function (user) {

    $scope.ctatus = true;

    var data = user;

    $scope.url = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/api'+'?name='+user.lastName;

    $http({
        method: $scope.method, 
        url: $scope.url, 
        cache: $templateCache
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.status = response.status;
        $scope.data = response.data;
        console.log(response);
      }, function(response) {
        $scope.data = response.data || "Request failed";
        $scope.status = response.status;
    });

};
```

на сервере

```
router.post('/api', function (req, res, netx) {
  res.json({name : 1});
  console.log(req.query);

});
```

На сервер все что нужно приходит, а вот ответ в виде json не возвращается и я не могу использовать отправленные данные в приложении. Как сделать нормальную интеграцию express и angular, ну хотя бы данные с сервера мог нормально забрать, без ошибок.

Comment: [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) и [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) не пробовали со стороны сервера использовать?

Comment: Так на сервере все нормально, о вот на клиенте все плохо

Comment: Как я понял вы с сервера посылаете простой пост вместо джейсона(из вопроса). Вот там и нужно переделать.

Comment: ответ ведь res.json({name : 1}) следовательно приходит ответ в формате json

Comment: `res.json({name : 1});` на `res.json(JSON.stringify({name : 1}));` попробуйте заменить

Comment: Я попробовал, то что вы написали, как я и думал это бред ( если точнее, то масло маслинное), но все равно спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Проблема заключается в то что нет доступа (по умолчанию) для того что бы использовать API с сторонних ресурсов, поэтому если у вас такая же проблема, то почитайте по CORS (http://enable-cors.org/) и у вас все получится!!!